# Set focus after first line of textarea prepend

Tags: jquery, focus

I am trying to set focus after i prepend something in a textarea that allready contains some content. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johneilif/qu25ztpp/) for example of what ive done so far. If i add .focus() after my prepend it only adds the focus at the end of textarea. not after the first line which I want to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// GET USER
 var signedInUser = document.getElementById('zz4_Menu').innerHTML;   
 var end = signedInUser.indexOf('<'); 
 var signedByUser = signedInUser.substring(6, end);

// DEFINE DATE
Date.prototype.getMinutesTwoDigits = function(){
    var retval = this.getMinutes();
    if (retval < 10){return ("0" + retval.toString());}
    else{return retval.toString();}
}
var timeStamp = new Date();
var currenttimeStamp = timeStamp.toLocaleDateString() + ', ' + timeStamp.getHours() + ":" + timeStamp.getMinutesTwoDigits();

// ADD BUTTON BEFORE TEXTBOX
$( '#textarea' ).before( '<p><a href="#" id="workLogBtn">Signer</a></p>' );

// ADD DETAILS TO TEXTBOX
  $('#workLogBtn').click(function(){
    $('#textarea').prepend(currenttimeStamp + '('  + signedByUser + ')' + ' - ' + '\n\n').focus();
  });
});
```

This is the code i have so far.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johneilif/qu25ztpp/)

Answer (score 0):

To set the cursor position you can use the next function:

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

example how to use:

```
$('#textarea').setCursorPosition(5);
```

Comment: That did nothing. Am I doing anything wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/johneilif/bmox4ceh/